# Roasting of toasts created in an activity that is a call from another class does not work

Tags: android, android-intent, gps, toast

From one class I am creating an activity defined in another class. This class has void methods, they do not return anything but if they print toast. Specifically they are gps values, the idea is to create the intent and print the values ​​for the moment but it does not work

The method from where I create the "GPsLocation" activity is "TornosAdapter" and has the following code

```
 holder.torn_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(c, "Puerta:" + t.getNumero_puerta() + "\nGeolocation: " + t.getGeolocation(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            //localizacion gps
            Log.d(TAG,"Pasa a crear el intent");
            //Here I create GpsLocation
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), GpsLocation.class);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
```

And the class where I define the GpsLocation activity with void methods and that do not work are these

```
    package com.gpasport.controlaccesos.controlaccesos;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.util.Log;


/**
 * Created by asanchez on 26/09/2017.
 */

public class GpsLocation extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG,"GpsLocation creating bundle activity");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);
        LocationManager milocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener milocListener = new MiLocationListener();
        milocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, milocListener);
    }

    public class MiLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            loc.getLatitude();
            loc.getLongitude();
            /*Prueba para imprimir la latiud por log*/
            Log.i(TAG,Double.toString(loc.getLatitude()));
            String coordenadas = "Mis coordenadas son: " + "Latitud = " + loc.getLatitude() + "Longitud = " + loc.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), coordenadas, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Desactivado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Activo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to know why it is failing, I am sure it is a problem of creating the activity. I have been looking at examples that work but the only difference is the communication with parameters with activities that in this

Comment: what is t there?

Comment: I don't understad  your question,the problem is no toast created and no log printed in debug

Comment: sorry..what is "t" in t.getNumero_puerta() ?and why are you creating intent?

Comment: "t" is object of door, and getNumbero_puerta() return a door number, in the class. This is class TornosAdapter and run correctly. the problem is GpsLocation.

Comment: I use intent to separate action to the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never start the `GpsLocation Activity`. You do this:

```
        //Here I create GpsLocation
        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), GpsLocation.class);
        toast.show();
```

but this does not start `GpsLocation`. You need to call `startActivity(intent)` after creating the `Intent`.

Comment: Thanks now working, and too net to change this line Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), GpsLocation.class);
                getContext().startActivity(intent);

Comment: If the answer was helpful to you, you should "accept" it by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer up/down arrows. This will get the question off the unanswered questions list.